# PHP - MySQL - Bind Multidimensional String Array to Prepared Statemens

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, prepared-statement

I am dynamically generating a query as below using a foreach loop:

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3, col4) values (?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?)
```

In the same loop I am creating and array of arrays containing 3 arrays with the values to be inserted. Now how can I bind this multi-dimensional array to my prepared statement? I saw samples running the "execute" of the statement inside the foreach loop for each set of values but I was wondering:

1- If that is the only way to achieve this and there is no way to bind a multi-dimensional array to a prepared statement

2- If executing a statement inside the foreach loop as in the samples I have seen will cause any problems writing to the database ([PHP prepared insert statement from multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535999/php-prepared-insert-statement-from-multidimensional-array))

Note: I am using MySQLi with object-oriented style.

Comment: *Not: I am not using PDO* instead of saying what you aren't using, why not say what you are? Because right now, we're still in the dark because we don't know what you're using.

Comment: Chances are you won't be able to bind a multi-dimensional array to the statement (we don't know), so you'll probably need to join them together into one large array.

Comment: @Script47  I am using MySQLi with object-oriented style. Sorry I am relatively new to PHP, hope this is clear.

Comment: @JonStirling Would that work? How would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Depends on your array and the keys you're using, but [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge) would potentially generate you a single array with all the params.

Comment: Saying that, doing it the way mentioned in the post you linked to and wrapped in a transaction may well be a nicer method imo.

Comment: @JonStirling Then I could bind this single array to my statement and execute the above query? Would that work? Thanks.

Comment: @Sr. I think so? Tias.